# Windows CURL download file- special char in URL

Tags: windows, command-line, file-transfer, curl, file-download

I need to download .xls file with Windows cURL and I have got a problem with URL of that file, because it contains special char "Č".

That URL is: [http://www.ccs.cz/data/141001_Seznam_ČStxt14196.xls](http://www.ccs.cz/data/141001_Seznam_%C4%8CStxt14196.xls)

I try it with this command in Windows command line or gitbash:

```
curl "http://www.ccs.cz/data/141001_Seznam_ČStxt14196.xls" > file.xls
```

Result is that I download a HTML file that contains information "this page not exists". I cannot encode URL to right form, which returns me that xls file.

Thank you very much for your advices.

Comment: I founded encoded version of that URL, which works in git bash: URL is: ccs.cz/datas/CCS%C4%8Cerpac%C3%ADstanice_10_351.2013_351.xls. But I need to write bat script, which will download that file and this url is still not working...

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using? PowerShell may be a more appropriate tool for you. If you have Win7 SP1, you'll need to update it to PowerShell 3.0 to get access to the essential cmdlets. Windows 8 or later has 3.0 baked in.

Answer (score 0):

This works in PowerShell on Windows 8.1. It should also be valid for PowerShell 3.0 or later on Windows 7 SP1 or later.

```
Invoke-WebRequest "http://www.ccs.cz/data/141001_Seznam_ČStxt14196.xls" -OutFile '141001_Seznam_ČStxt14196.xls'
```

`Invoke-WebRequest` is PowerShell's equivalent to curl. Since PowerShell handles special characters a bit more gracefully than CMD, no URL encoding is required. However, since PowerShell also provides access to classes in the underlying .NET Framework, you can use something like `[URI]::EscapeDataString()` to do encoding when it is needed.

For more information, see the following MSDN/TechNet articles:

[Invoke-WebRequest](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx)
[URI Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)